# What is the openGL behavior for feeding a texture ID to the glDeleteBuffers?

Tags: opengl, buffer

(instead of using glDeleteTextures)
Is it undefined ? 
Will it delete the texture buffer anyway ? (a buffer is a buffer. No ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that.

From the docs,

> `glDeleteBuffers` silently ignores 0's and names that do not correspond to existing buffer objects.

So, it's bad, but it won't necessarily crash your program.  Your program may just find some of its buffer objects unexpectedly deleted (well, this *will* crash your program if you try to map the buffers but don't check for errors).

Answer (score 3):

It's undefined.

It's possible that an OpenGL implementation might use a single set of names across textures and buffers, and in that case then it might just work. However, I once called the wrong glDelete on OSX on a title in development and it managed to crash the OS occasionally (required a power cycle), so it's definitely a very dangerous thing to be doing.

Comment: Got it :-) Thank you !